# Callback implementation

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know a low-level implementation on how callback is implemented in ROS. Does it use `function pointers`, `function objects` or `commands and Hollywood` or any others. Could somebody point me to any of its implementations.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31328/callback-implementation/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Function callbacks are based on C++ functor objects. roscpp normally uses something that's compatible with the return value of boost::bind, e.g. boost::function. There are a bunch of overloaded versions of subscribe that take normal function pointers though. Internally, these methods just use boost::bind to generate the functor object. Have a look at roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-04-05**:
Thanks for the information and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many different callbacks.

I believe most are implemented with [`boost::bind()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-04-05**:
Thanks a lot for the information.